# how to use socket fetch webpage use python

Tags: python, http, sockets

i know use urllib2 to fetch webpage is easy,
but i want to know is there an sample for use socket implement fetch webpage function,
i google a lot,i didn't found any example in this,could any one help?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: http://blog.tonycode.com/tech-stuff/http-notes/making-http-requests-via-telnet Is a decent example of how to perform the raw requests via telnet which can be directly translated to `python` socket sends.

Comment: http is based on socket stream protocal,so if i could know how to implement it under urllib2,than i can know more knowledge & backgroud on http

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's something I whipped up. It doesn't catch exceptions to handle errors.  YMMV

```
import socket
request = b"GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: stackoverflow.com\n\n"
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("stackoverflow.com", 80))
s.send(request)
result = s.recv(10000)
while (len(result) > 0):
    print(result)
    result = s.recv(10000)
```

Comment: I always wondered what socket examples looked like. Thankfully I use requests or urllib. Might look into learning socket so I can appreciate it more than I do now.

Comment: it doesn't catch exception doesn't mean it won't, You should put your connection code under try catch block to avoid it.

Comment: I have a service with the path "http://example.com/sensors/premises" how can I apply this code to make a GET request? i tried to put my domain name into Host definition and put it also into connect function, but always get a Forbedden response from the service, even though from the browser the same URL is available.