# python socket GET

Tags: python, python-sockets

From the other posts on stack overflow this should be working

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)                 

s.connect(("www.cnn.com" , 80))
s.sendall("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n")
print s.recv(4096)
s.close
```

but for some reason it just hangs (at `recv`) and never prints. I know that a request to www.cnn.com will chunk it's data but I should at least read something from `recv`, right?

> p.s. I know this isn't the best way to do it and that there are library like `httplib` and `urllib2` out there, but I can't use those for this project (it's for school). I have to use the `socket` library

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You forgot to send a blank line after your request line:

```python
s.sendall("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n")
```

Furthermore, HTTP 1.1 specifies you should add the `Host` header field as documented in the [Host section in the HTTP 1.1 RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23).

```python
s.sendall("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.cnn.com\r\n\r\n")
```

Comment: Pardon my noobness, why is a Host header required if the socket connected to it?

Comment: To allow name based virtual hosting: When you connect to the hostname, the hostname is resolved (using DNS) to an IP-address, and the actual TCP-connection is to the IP-address. So, if you'd host several websites on the same server, using only one IP-address, the client would not know which website you were trying to connect to. By passing the "Host"-header the webserver knows which website you are trying to access. [Virtual Hosting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting)

Answer (score 8):

Your code is almost right, but you need to send 2 `\r\n` sequences to satisfy the HTTP protocol.

A valid GET request will look like this (note 2 lines):

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
```

So your code should be:

```
s.sendall('GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n')
```

Further to that, there are additional headers required for valid HTTP 1.1 requests, such as `Host:`. You need to add them to your request, something like this:

```
s.sendall('''GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: cnn.com

''')
```

Comment: This does answer my questions and was first so I guess I'll make this correct. For others, see my own answer as well

Comment: @jamessmith: you should choose the best answer, not the first answer. Anyway, I think that Takis answered first :)

Answer (score 6):

Sorry to waste everyone's time. I just found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140914/how-to-use-socket-fetch-webpage-use-python) on Stack Overflow (just took some rewording in my Google search to find)

```
import socket
request = b"GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: www.cnn.com\n\n"
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("cnn.com", 80))
s.send(request)
result = s.recv(10000)
while (len(result) > 0):
    print(result)
    result = s.recv(10000)
```

And all of the answers were right as well about the ending `\r\n\r\n` however those returned `301` statuses. This solution seems to follow the redirect somehow? Anyways, this solutions worked for me

Comment: That code gives a 302 response. It does not follow the redirect. Do you need to handle redirects for your school project?

Answer (score 3):

I am cleaning up the examples for Python 3. We need bytes/string conversion and we can also use automatic closing of the connection using `with`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:

    s.connect(("example.com" , 80))
    s.sendall(b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\nAccept: text/html\r\n\r\n")
    print(str(s.recv(4096), 'utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 2):

@james: you did a SlowLoris attack there without aware of it. I can't explain better than here, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XiFkyR35v2Y
I assumed that you found the solution from all the above answers but I just answered to bring this to your knowledge. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try replace this line:

```
s.sendall("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n")
```

with:

```
s.sendall("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n")
                             ^^^^
```

Also, I think you need replace `s.close` with `s.close()` since it's a function.