# Starting a TCP client with python

Tags: python, python-sockets

I'm learning ethical hacking with Python, and I have been trying to type a simple TCP client from BlackHat python book, but I have problems running the code I have written from the book.

```py
import socket

target_host = "95.127.145.5"
target_post = 80

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((target_host,target_post))

client = send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 95.127.145.5\r\n\r\n")

response = client.recv(4096)
```

I'm  not sure if it's because it's python2 but if it is, I need advice on how to convert this code to python3 because my IDE is python 3.8.3
 the error happens in `("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 95.127.145.5\r\n\r\n")` and I get the message "inspect type checker options".
Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34192093/python-socket-get

Comment: _I get the message "inspect type checker options"_ Is that all the output?

Answer (score 1):

You have to encode the text before sending the request,
This line is also wrong

```
client = send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 95.127.145.5\r\n\r\n")
```

It should be :

```
client.send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 95.127.145.5\r\n\r\n")
```

See :

```
import socket

target_host = "95.127.145.5"
target_post = 80

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((target_host,target_post))

client.send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 95.127.145.5\r\n\r\n".encode())

response = client.recv(4096)
```

Also check whether the host is up or not

Comment: my bad there was a typo on that, i typed correctly just have problem on it sending on python3, but thank you your help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In python2,

```
client = send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 95.127.145.5\r\n\r\n")
```

should be

```
client.send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 95.127.145.5\r\n\r\n")
```

In python3, it just needs to be

```
client.send(b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 95.127.145.5\r\n\r\n")
```

edit: Roshin Raphel's answer does the encoding better than mine. And you're not using `target_host` when making up the request. So that line is probably better being

```
client.send(f"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {target_host}\r\n\r\n".encode())
```

Comment: thank you so much for this answer, it is highly appreciated

Comment: i started getting this <built-in method recv of socket object at 0x006E2928>

Comment: I think you may have done `response=client.recv` and not `response=client.recv(4096)`

Comment: thats a typo i made in there