# Reading content in website, not able to open

Tags: python, web

I'm using Python 2.7.9

I tried open and reading a website but I get errors like:
11001 getaddrsinfo
OR
no connection ... machine actively refused it

In fact when I try to open a website with the purpose of reading it I'm never able to open it.
I believe the problem is a configuration of the system.
With webdriver I can open a website but don't know how to read that content. Can you help please?

Here is the code I used, with different possibilities but always with the same errors.

```
    import socket
import os
os.environ['http_proxy'] = '127.0.0.1:8080'
import requests, re
import urllib2
#from urllib2 import urlopen 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
from six.moves import urllib
# as req

#from urllib.request import urlopen

def news ():

    url = "http://www.edureka.co/"
    #payload = {'q': 'shape of you'}
    #r = requests.get(url, params = payload)
##  socket.getaddrinfo('127.0.0.1', 8080)
##  r = requests.get(url)
##  soup = bs(r.text,"html.parser")

#   html = urlopen(url).read()

#   soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
#https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/
    #webbrowser.register('chrome',  None,
    #webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser("C://Program Files (x86)//Google//Chrome//Application//chrome.exe"))
    
##  link = soup.find('a', {'href':re.compile('http://www.edureka.co/')})['href']
    #link = "http://www.edureka.co/"
    link = 'http://www.edureka.co/'
    print(link)
    #proxies = {'http': 'http://www.someproxy.com:3128'}
    #proxies = {'http': 'http://www.edureka.co/'}
    #f = urllib.urlopen(link, proxies={})
    #proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': '127.0.0.1'})
### proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({})
### opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support)
### urllib2.install_opener(opener)
### in_ = opener.open(link)
### in_.read()

##  result = urllib2.urlopen(link)
    #result = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
    #f = urllib2.Request('http://www.edureka.co/')


    socket.getaddrinfo('localhost', 8080)
    mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    mysock.connect(("www.edureka.co/", 80))
    #mysock.send('GET http://www.edureka.co/ HTTP/1.0\n\n')
##  f2 = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.edureka.co/')
##  my = f2.read()

    #HTMLParser.feed('http://www.edureka.co/')
    

    #import requests
    #s = requests.Session()
    #url = requests.form['http://www.edureka.co/']
##  r = req.get('http://www.edureka.co')
##  print(r.status_code)
    #req = requests.get('<a href="http://www.edureka.co/">http://www.edureka.co/</a>')

##  r.encoding # returns 'utf-8'
##  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser').get_text()

##  print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: take a look the `requests` module. Also when you use a socket to send that information, your order might be wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34192093/python-socket-get

Answer (score 1):

Something You are Looking for is called "Web Scraping".

The following code performs an HTTP request to the given URL. It retrieves the HTML data that the server sends back and stores that data in a Python object.

```
import requests

URL     = 'http://www.edureka.co/'
page    = requests.get(URL)
```

You can combine this with "beautifulsoap" to parse your html that will be like the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

URL     = 'http://www.edureka.co/'
page    = requests.get(URL)
soup    = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(id='auto_banner_load')

print (results)
```

This Works fine and produces no errors, you have to read "requests" and "beautifulsoap" documentaions depended on the actual action you are trying to perform.

For more information just take a loot at [This Link](https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python/)!