# Python: get json data from https url using sockets

Tags: python, api, sockets, python-requests, python-sockets

I need to get some json data using API

```
import requests

url = 'https://example.com/api/some-info/'
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.text)  # Here is JSON needeed
```

And everything fine, except I need to make such requests very often, and API provider says:

> You'll be banned if you make more than 5 requests per second, so use
>   sockets

So, how can I make this work via sockets?
Big thx for advices.

Comment: https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: @RahulKP, We should make maximum requests as possible requests=) It is very for business) And, yes it is an option, but I am also interested in how can sockets can help with DDoS protection)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140914/how-to-use-socket-fetch-webpage-use-python